# BitcoinJ: Is it possible to always use the same receive address?

Tags: bitcoinj

I need to create a wallet that receives coins from a third party that never changes.

Reading the [wallet](http://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12.3/) documentation, I've understood there is a method that returns the public receive address:

```
Address address = wallet.currentAddress();
```

Then, the documentation also says that once the current address is seen being used, it changes to a new one.

Does this mean that once my wallet receives some coins I need to tell my third party the address changed? Maybe I've misunderstood things... but I just need to provide my third party with an address and they'll send coins to this address whenever necessary.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can reuse old address. But It is best practise to create new address for each transaction to keep hidden yourself how much money a single person holds.
You can iterate over the list of ECKey to check how many addresses being hold by in your wallet.

Comment: We never hold incoming bitcoins... we forward them to target recipients (which always have different addresses) immediately, i.e. we just act as a temporary broker.